# How to make expressions computable in custom directive? (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom directive:

```
<custom-directive style='height: {{window.innerHeight + "px"}}'></custom-directive>

myApp.directive('customDirective', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/views/controls/customTemplate.html'
        };
});
```

So, the expression `style='height: {{window.innerWidth + "px"}}'` doesn't work. App just ignores it. How to make it work?

Comment: Write styling code in link function of custom directive not on view, it will work then.

Comment: Can you put the plunkr

Comment: @AmitSirohiya, how to do this? Sorry, I am new to angularjs.

Comment: Do you have a window attribute in the controller scope? Because expressions are always evaluated on the scope. They can't use global variables like window.

Comment: @AmitSirohiya, I understand already. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a link function in directive where you will get directive element as and argument use that to change the css of the element.

Like if you want to change the color of the directive text do like this -

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
   elem.css('color','red');
}
```

**Diective**

```
    myApp.directive('customDirective', function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: '/views/controls/customTemplate.html',
                link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                        elem.css('color','red');
                }
            };
    });
```